# How to design support for tens of thousands of emails a day and connect it with ecommerce transaction system?

Tags: performance, email, elasticsearch, imap, erp

i have a problem with performance in my project. I made a system that supports the e-commerce orders. One of my client have a over 10k orders per day. I wrote email module. In this moment i download,send emails from 50 inbox, parse it, and i connect it with object in system.
This is about 50-100k emails per day.

Current process:

1. Connect to all of inbox - IMAP.
2. Search email without special TAG
3. Download emails, parse and create message object in system.
4. Set special tag on imap.

This solution is very havy to IMAP server and for my postgres database.
I think about copy email from imap to elasticsearch and use elasticsearch in email module.

Maybe someone had a similar problem and found the best solution?

Comment: Stop using IMAP.  Have the mail system funnel emails directly to your script. (Eg, set a script as a filter in your SMTP server or the like).  Eg, use a push system, not a pull system.

Comment: I understend your solution, but i think about other clinets. Most use o365 or Gsuite.
It will be hard to get rid of imap.

Comment: I would be very surprised if these didn't have some sort of solution for queuing messages into another system, though I haven't explored the admin settings for these solutions.